# Livewire/Bootstrap - Issue Passing Value to Input Before Displaying Livewire/Bootstrap Modal

Tags: php, laravel, data-binding, modal-dialog, laravel-livewire

I have two distinct buttons that should trigger the opening of the modal ($('#create-ponto-atipico').modal('show');). Depending on which button is clicked, I need to pass a different value to an input field within the modal.

Additional Information:

I'm using Bootstrap 3.4, Laravel 7, and PHP 7.4 with Livewire 2.12.
I'm available to provide further details if needed.
I'm developing a project in PHP using the Laravel framework, where I'm using Livewire to compose my components. In a specific view of my application, I have a Livewire component that is called using the following code:

```
@livewire('create-ponto-atipico')
@livewireScripts
```

However, I'm having trouble passing a specific value to an input field within the Livewire modal before displaying it.

```
create-ponto-atipico.view
<div class="modal fade" id="create-ponto-atipico" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="create-ponto-atipico" aria-hidden="true"
    wire:ignore.self>
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form wire:submit.prevent="save">
                {{-- TODO: PASSAR O TIPO DE INPUT PARA DENTRO DO CONTROLADOR --}}
                <input type="text" id="tipo_entrada_modal" wire:model="tipo_entrada" hidden>
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
                            aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h5 class="modal-title fs-5" id="create-ponto-atipico">Selecionar data e horário</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div>
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend class="form-label ml-3">Data</legend>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control daterange" id="data_submissao"
                                wire:model.defer="data_submissao"
                                onchange="this.dispatchEvent(new InputEvent('input'))">
                        </fieldset>
                        @error('data_submissao')
                            <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mt-4">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <fieldset>
                                <legend class="form-label ml-3">Manhã</legend>
                                <label for="entrada_manha" class="form-label">Entrada</label>
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" id="entrada_manha"
                                    wire:model.defer="entrada_manha">
                                @error('entrada_manha')
                                    <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                                @enderror
                                <label for="saida_manha" class="form-label">Saída</label>
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" id="saida_manha"
                                    wire:model.defer="saida_manha">
                                @error('saida_manha')
                                    <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                                @enderror
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <fieldset>
                                <legend class="form-label ml-3">Tarde</legend>
                                <label for="entrada_tarde" class="form-label">Entrada</label>
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" id="entrada_tarde"
                                    wire:model.defer="entrada_tarde">
                                @error('entrada_tarde')
                                    <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                                @enderror
                                <label for="saida_tarde" class="form-label">Saída</label>
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" id="saida_tarde"
                                    wire:model.defer="saida_tarde">
                                @error('saida_tarde')
                                    <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                                @enderror
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <fieldset>
                                <legend class="form-label ml-3">Noite</legend>
                                <label for="entrada_noite" class="form-label">Entrada</label>
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" id="entrada_noite"
                                    wire:model.defer="entrada_noite">
                                @error('entrada_noite')
                                    <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                                @enderror
                                <label for="saida_noite" class="form-label">Saída</label>
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" id="saida_noite"
                                    wire:model.defer="saida_noite">
                                @error('saida_noite')
                                    <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                                @enderror
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submeter</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
class CreatePontoAtipico extends Component
{

    public $data_submissao = "";
    public $entrada_manha = "";
    public $saida_manha = "";
    public $entrada_tarde = "";
    public $saida_tarde = "";
    public $entrada_noite = "";
    public $saida_noite = "";
    public $tipo_entrada = "";

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.create-ponto-atipico');
    }

    public function save()
    {
        $this->validate([
            'data' => 'required',
        ]);

        //return to dashboard view
        $dia_hoje = Carbon::now();
        $mes_hoje = $dia_hoje->month;
        $ano_hoje = $dia_hoje->year;
        return redirect()->to('/dashboard/' . $ano_hoje . '/' . $mes_hoje);
    }
}
```

I have every other input field in the controller, besides the tipo_entrada.

[image: This ilustrates how the request in being passed to the controller]

- I tried using the Bootstrap show.bs.modal event to set the value of the input field before displaying the modal, but it didn't work.
- also tried setting the value of the input field before displaying the modal using JavaScript, but without success.

```
$('#create-ponto-atipico').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
    var tipo = button.data('tipo');
    var modal = $(this);
    modal.find('.modal-body #tipo_entrada_modal').val(tipo);
});
```

- I tried to set the #tipo_entrada_modal with JS didn't worked aswell

```
$("#tipo_entrada_modal").prop('value', 'trabalho');
```

- I tried to Livewire.emit it aswell

```
window.livewire.emit('set:tipo_entrada', 'trabalho');
```

- I tried to update the hidden input with jquery

```
$('#tipo_entrada_modal').attr('value','trabalho');
```

The input inside the modal has the value 'trabalho', but when I submit the form, $tipo_entrada is null.

I hope someone can help me with this !

Answer (score 0):

Okey I found a solution. Maybe I think I can better explain what I wanted to achieve, and how I achieved it.
I've a blade view file wich contains two buttons to add working days or abscent days.
At the beggining, clicking the buttons would submit a for with input's select from that view. Now, i want to add a modal to insert a custom working day or abscent day if none of the input in the view were select.
I designed a livewire component for the modal, i could open the modal.
My first trouble was stopping the modal from auto submiting. Achieved that with wire:model.defer.
The  second problem was : I couldn't distinguish wich button triggered the modal. I tried everything.
Ended up with JS submiting it to the modal with a Livewire.emit() that would set the variable !

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).